# Using pircBot on Twitch and Get Game Title

Tags: java, bots, irc, twitch

I'm writing a bot for Twitch.tv in Java and am using pircBot. I'm trying to figure out if there's a method I can use to get the game that's being played from the channel. For example, the game that's being played in a channel that I send it to is Dark Souls or Dota 2, I want to get that information, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no API available for Twitch.tv, then the only way would be to parse the entire page and search the page for the specific games.